# Creating a new list based on their position

Tags: python, list

So there is a list which contains

```
'3,2,5,4,1','3,1,2,5,4','2,5,1,4,3'
```

These numbers are part of the same list, HOWEVER they are strings in a list(ie. list 1)

and from this, you say that for the "first row", 3 occurs at position 0, 2 occurs at position 1, 5 at 2 etc.
For the "second row", 3 occurs at position 0, 1 occurs at position 1, 2 occurs at position 2 etc.

I would like to create a loop or anything at all (besides using imported functions) to create a final list which looks like

```
0: [3, 3, 2]
1: [2, 1, 5]
2: [5, 2, 1]
3: [4, 5, 4]
4: [1, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Single line of code using `Dictionary comprehension` and `List comprehension` :

```
>>> { col:[row[col] for row in l] for col in range(len(l[0])) }
=> {0: [3, 3, 2], 1: [2, 1, 5], 2: [5, 2, 1], 3: [4, 5, 4], 4: [1, 4, 3]}
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [[3,2,5,4,1], 
          [3,1,2,5,4],
          [2,5,1,4,3]]
```

**NOTE to OP** : what your `output` suggests is a `Dictionary` by looking at its structure. A `list` cannot be defined in the same manner.

**EDIT :** Since the OP's `list` is a `list of strings`, first convert that to a `list of int` using `map` and then continue as above.

```
>>> l = ['3,2,5,4,1', '3,1,2,5,4', '2,5,1,4,3']

>>> l = [list(map(int,s.split(','))) for s in l]

>>> l
=> [[3, 2, 5, 4, 1], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4], [2, 5, 1, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! 
There is an issue where the comma in between the numbers are considered a position. As such instead of wanting 5 positions, i will get 8 as the commas are included. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @H.Y : From the looks of it, am guessing your `list` is actually a `list` of `string`. If that is the case, small modification will have to be made. So pls post the `exact list` you are using

Comment: @H.Y , check the edit. Have listed how to work with `list of string` .

Answer (score 1):

Transposition of a two-dimensional list can simply be done using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
In [1]: l = [[3,2,5,4,1],
   ...:      [3,1,2,5,4],
   ...:      [2,5,1,4,3]]
In [2]: t = list(zip(*l))
In [3]: t
Out[3]: [(3, 3, 2), (2, 1, 5), (5, 2, 1), (4, 5, 4), (1, 4, 3)]
```

To output that in the format described above:

```
In [4]: for n,line in enumerate(t):
   ...:     print("{}: {}".format(n, list(line)))
   ...:
0: [3, 3, 2]
1: [2, 1, 5]
2: [5, 2, 1]
3: [4, 5, 4]
4: [1, 4, 3]
```